# How to reference SystemFolder in WiX Icon.SourceFile property?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

To make the long story short, this doesn't work:

```
<Icon Id="msiexec.ico" SourceFile="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe"/>
```

(Error  4 The system cannot find the file '[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe')

And this doesn't work too:

```
<Icon Id="msiexec.ico" SourceFile="$(var.SystemFolder)msiexec.exe"/>
```

Error 3 Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.SystemFolder)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sample in your question will work if you pass `var.SystemFolder` as a parameter to `candle.exe`.

The `<Icon>` element is mapped to the [Icon MSI table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa369210.aspx). **At build time** it tries to find the path you specify in `SourceFile` attribute and stream it as binary data to the `Data` column of the Icon table. This means, the path should be known at build time. But this is not true in your first sample - `SystemFolder` is resolved at install time.

Comment: Then it means hardcoding the path I'm passing to candle.exe and won't be any better then just writingSourceFile="C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe"

I'm gonna accept your answer, but shouldn't there be a way of getting the resolved property here?

Comment: @lonelyass: The `Icon` element will resolve the file in the same way as a `File` element. So you can just extract the icon from msiexec and  put it among the files which get included in the setup.

Comment: I agree, @WimCoenen, extracting the icon and placing it together with other files is a good idea.